# Null layout - components hide after repainting

Tags: java

So I have big panel with: setLayout(null). Then I want to add button to it. In big panel's constructor I add such code:

```
JButton button = new JButton("eeee");
button.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 50);
add(button);
```

And it's okay. But when I repaint big panel button hides. It appears again when I move mouse to place where it should be... How to prevent this strange behaviour? Maybe its connected with the fact I add button in constrcutor?

Comment: you override the method "paint"?

Comment: yes I do. In paint method I draw objects from arrayList

Comment: Doing this in constructor is fine. Are you sure it's a JPanel: you haven't used awt.Panel by mistake?   Or, are you overriding paint, paintComponent, etc.?

Comment: EDIT: I got it. I overrid paint insted of paintComponent. My mistake

Answer (score 0):

you need to let the paint panel components first with "super.paint (g)" if you do not it does not draw the components added

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g); //draw your button as default
    // hear, you can draw others things 

}
```